# Choisir entre « au choix » et « aux choix »

Tags: sens, expressions, choix-de-mot

Entre « au choix » et « aux choix », laquelle des expressions est plus juste ?

Comment: Il faut préciser le contexte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'expression figée est « **au [choix](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/choix)** » car elle met devant **un** choix, pas devant **des** choix.

On rencontre cependant des « aux choix », soit simplement erronés, soit parce qu'il ne s'agit pas de l'expression précédente mais d'une autre construction, par exemple :

> Ceux qui se sont opposés **aux choix** dictés par le chef de la Maison-Blanche ont dû quitter leurs fonctions (*Charles Philippe David*, Au sein de la Maison-Blanche, 2004, p170)

Comment: And to add to this, asker should remember that "au" will *always* mean "only one", and "aux" will *always* mean "more than one". Choices have nothing to do with this choice. :)